# かれはまどをあけますか — How to convert it to "Why did he open the window?"

Tags: questions

I am a beginner. I know

> Did he open the window?
>   かれはまどをあけましたか。

I just don't know where to insert the "why" in the sentence.

**Update:** I forgot it is あけました because of "did". I can construct simple questions of when, where, why, who, what. So, this can be どうしてかれはまどをあけましたか。for "Why did he open the window?"?

Comment: 1) `I know Did he open the window? - かれはまどをあけますか` -> かれはまどをあけま**す**か is the present tense, "Does/Will he open~?" The past tense "Did he open~?" would be かれはまどをあけま**した**か. 2) `I just don't know where to insert the "why" in the sentence` -> Just put it anywhere you like, and you'd be understood most of the time. Show us your attempt first, and we'll always be ready to help

Comment: Do read [the link provided in the close reason](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/542). Our site's scope does not include direct translation requests and alternative sites have been recommended in the meta-post. I'm sorry you feel disappointed, but in the first revision of this question your question is off-topic for our site.

Comment: Questions can be formed simply by adding the question marker か to a sentence. Do you know how to form questions with a question word such as *when*, *where*, *why*, *who*, *what*, etc.?

Comment: "on hold" means that we need more information from you (over on the original question) to make it on-topic and open to answers.

Comment: Yes, I forgot it is あけました because of "did". I can construct simple questions of when, where, why, who, what. So, this can be　どうしてかれはまどをあけましたか。for "Why did he open the window?"?

Comment: I merged you two questions. You should also have your two accounts merged (via the "contact us" link at the bottom of your profile).

Answer (score 3):

> I know Did he open the window? - かれはまどをあけますか。

かれはまどをあけま**す**か is the present tense, "Does/Will he open the window?"

To say "**Did** he open the window?", you say かれはまどをあけま**した**か。

> I just don't know where to insert the "why" in the sentence.

Just put it anywhere and you'd be understood most of the time, but I think we usually put it at the beginning of the sentence or right after the subject, so you get:

> **どうして**かれはまどをあけましたか。
>   かれは**どうして**まどをあけましたか。
>   **なぜ**かれはまどをあけましたか。
>   かれは**なぜ**まどをあけましたか。

These above sentences make sense and are grammatically correct (I believe), but I think it'd be more natural (in real life, at least) to say:

> どうしてかれはまどをあけた**んですか**。
>   かれはどうしてまどをあけた**んですか**。
>   なぜかれはまどをあけた**んですか**。
>   かれはなぜまどをあけた**んですか**。

... ending with んですか (which is the contracted form of のですか), using the explanatory の.

どうして is more casual than なぜ, as you might know.