# かれはまどをあけますか。How to convert it to “Why did he open the window?”

Tags: grammar

I am a beginner Nihongo learner. I know Did he open the window? - かれはまどをあけますか。I just don't know where to insert the "why" in the sentence. Actually, I was a little disappointed that this question is put on hold, thinking that people here is not that helpful to people like me.

Comment: ちょっとｗｗ　コメント読んでほしかったなー　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38711/%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8c%e3%81%af%e3%81%be%e3%81%a9%e3%82%92%e3%81%82%e3%81%91%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-how-to-convert-it-to-why-did-he-open-the-window#comment73743_38711